# How to add a build for testing?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I've uploaded my build using Xcode 7, but now I can't send it to internal testers.
[image]

This popup contains list of builds for external testers only.
What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR make sure the internal testers are already part of your iTunes Connect account.  Apple's documentation is surprisingly good for this feature.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html